# Rake aborted: "ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate, rakefile

When trying to execute:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The terminal answers:

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `require'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `require'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize_tasks'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/Charles/rails_projects/demo_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

None of the solutions proposed here (specially downgrading the gem, or modifying the Rakefile (hereafter) work (rake version 10.0.1)

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

DemoApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using rails version 3.0.5.  Update your Gemfile to `gem 'rails', '3.0.20'` and then run `bundle update rails`

Answer (score 0):

specify your rake version to 0.8.7 into Gemfile and execute the command bundle exec rake db:migrate